# how to simply following code, Dataframe, iteration, for

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

1. I have dadaframe named "data" and want to simply angle as following code.
2. it took lots of time to run. is there any good solution for soliving this issue?

   ```
   for i in range(0,len(data)):
       if data['Theta'][i]<=np.pi/8 and data['Theta'][i]>=0: 
          data['Theta'][i]=0
       elif data['Theta'][i]<=3*np.pi/8 and data['Theta'][i]>1*np.pi/8: 
            data['Theta'][i] = np.pi/4
       elif data['Theta'][i]<=np.pi and data['Theta'][i]>3*np.pi/8: 
            data['Theta'][i] = np.arctan(2)
       elif data['Theta'][i]<=13*np.pi/8 and data['Theta'][i]>np.pi: 
            data['Theta'][i] = np.arctan(-2)
       elif data['Theta'][i] <= 15 * np.pi/8 and data['Theta'][i] >13*np.pi/8:
            data['Theta'][i] = -1*np.pi/4
       elif data['Theta'][i] >=15 * np.pi / 8 and data['Theta'][i] <= 2*np.pi:
            data['Theta'][i] = 0
   ```

Comment: You can create a mask for each condition `data.loc[(data['Theta']<=np.pi/8) & (data['Theta']>=0), 'Theta'] = 0` and so on, so it operates on all rows that meet the condition

Comment: i am beginner, could you explain more in detail??

Comment: Replace your loop with `data.loc[(data['Theta']<=np.pi/8) & (data['Theta']>=0), 'Theta'] = 0` then `data.loc[(data['Theta']<=3*np.pi/8) & (data['Theta']>1*np.pi/8), 'Theta'] = np.pi/4` and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a function doing what you want and then apply it on all rows, it should be fast.

```
def f(x):
    if x <= np.pi / 8 and x >=0:
        x = 0
    elif x <= 3 * np.pi / 8 and x > 1 * np.pi / 8:
        x = np.pi / 4
    elif x <= np.pi and x > 3 * np.pi / 8:
        x = np.arctan(2)
    elif x <= 13 * np.pi / 8 and x > np.pi:
        x = np.arctan(-2)
    elif x <= 15 * np.pi / 8 and x > 13 * np.pi / 8:
        x = -1 * np.pi / 4
    elif x >= 15 * np.pi / 8 and x <= 2 * np.pi:
         x = 0
    return x

data["Theta"] = data["Theta"].apply(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be faster if you create masks for each condition:

```
data.loc[(data['Theta']<=np.pi/8) & (data['Theta']>=0), 'Theta'] = 0 data.loc[(data['Theta']<=3*np.pi/8) & (data['Theta']>1*np.pi/8), 'Theta'] = np.pi/4 
data.loc[(data['Theta']<=np.pi) & (data['Theta']>3*np.pi/8), 'Theta'] = np.arctan(2)
data.loc[(data['Theta']<=3*np.pi/8) & (data['Theta']>np.pi), 'Theta'] = np.arctan(-2) 
data.loc[(data['Theta']<=15*np.pi/8) & (data['Theta']>13*np.pi/8), 'Theta'] = -1*np.pi/4 
data.loc[(data['Theta']>=15*np.pi/8) & (data['Theta']<2*np.pi), 'Theta'] = 0
```

So this uses `loc` and a mask where we compare all rows in the df against the condition, this will return a boolean mask that masks the entire df so only the rows where the condition is met are updated. Additionally we have to use `&` instead of `and` as you're comparing arrays and not scalar values. We also need to wrap the conditions in parentheses due to operator precedence.